# Accessing Remote Desktop Clipboard

Tags: clipboard, remote-desktop

I am accessing my desktop from my laptop via MSTSC. On the RDC session I have selected the option to allow access to my local resources for Printer and Clipboard.

I can copy and paste from my local laptop to my remore desktop, but cannot copy and paste from my remote to my local. This worked last week, but has now stopped.

What setting might have changed?

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forget me. Found the answer on SuperUser (obviously!!) -

https://superuser.com/questions/220453/fixing-copy-paste-for-remote-desktop-sessions linking to http://brennan.offwhite.net/blog/2007/01/18/fixing-copypaste-for-remote-desktop-sessions/

Answer (score 6):

the problem in the remote host here how to solve it :-
1. Login to remote computer using Remote Desktop (RDP)

1. Open Task Manager in the remote machine
2. Click the "Process" tab
3. Locate a program called "rdpclip.exe"
4. Right click and select "End process" to kill this program
5. Click on "File" menu in the task manager and select "New Task (Run)"
6. Type rdpclip.exe and press the button to start the process.

Comment: Thanks for copying the answer from the previously identified links... :-|

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but I just needed to download some files from an external server. So, in the RDC local settings, I selected the 'more' option and selected a local drive such as C: to be available in my remote session. Then on the remote server, when navigating to "My Computer", my local C: drive is available for transfer of files.